# What's the best way to store 5000 dataframes (each 1000 x 5) in an HDF store?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have ~5000 dataframes, each with about 1000 x 5 floats.

I currently store them in a manner similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import tables

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(1000, 5))

hdf = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

for i in range(5000):
    hdf.put('/a{j}/b{i}/c{i}'.format(i=i, j=int(i/100)), df, format='table')
```

I can check for existence like this:

```
'a0/b0/c0' in hdf
```

And that returns instantly.  I can also do an hdf.get('a0/b0/c0'), and that returns a dataframe immediately.

However, if I actually try to list keys or groups explicitly (`hdf.keys()` or `hdf.groups()`), it takes several seconds (5 to 10 seconds) to return.

- Why are keys() and groups() taking so long?  Is the HDF store not meant to have that many nodes?
- Is there a faster way to iterate through all the groups or nodes under one group?  Let's say I want to iterate over the 1000 dataframes under the 'a0' group; how would I do that?

Comment: Why not just have this as one frame it's not very big.

Comment: That's a toy example, but in reality, the columns may vary across the ~50 top level groups, so I'd have a pretty sparse matrix.  But I'm beginning to think that may just be easiest anyway. Why IS iterating through groups so slow, though? Is it an HDF5 thing? Or HDF5 in Python?